# Bad guy lands on planet unaware of blue giant sun

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Hoping for pointer to story.

Person lands on planet [having done something bad] in space lifeboat with no windows.

Planet has two or three suns.

Does bad things on planet.  Small children he meets warn him about a danger.

Gets comeuppance when caught out in open when the really big blue giant sun rises and he burns quickly to a crisp

Blue sun may be named "Grandpa"

Last line may be something like "and then [through the rock he was trying to hide behind] Grandpa reached out and touched him"

Story in English

Published as part of an anthology, in a hardbound book in a school library

Comment: Is this a novel? Short story?

Comment: Any idea when you read it, in what language etc?

Comment: Short story in English,  part of hardbound anthology found in junior high school library

Comment: [Run to the rock, rock won't you hide me. And the Lord said, sinner man, the rock will be melting](https://www.lyricszoo.com/alvin-ailey-american-dance-theater/sinner-man/).

Answer (score 12):

This is "Page and Player" by Jerome Bixby, a novelette published in the August 1952 STARTLING STORIES and then reprinted in Andre Norton's YA anthology SPACE PIONEERS. The paraphrased line is not the last line, but there's a passage near the end of the story that corresponds:

> Grandpa shoved his gigantic blue-white shoulder over the horizon and the sky seemed to explode into flame.
>
> Blinded instantly, Jord turned and fled.  He stumbled, crashed shrieking down a long slope to huddle slant-wise behind a boulder.  And through the racing, churning clouds, through the uncaring stone, Grandpa reached out, touched him....